# Viewport Resizing on Desktop Browsers

Tags: css, browser, media-queries, viewport

I have a client who wanted a responsive site which caters to screens from 1400px wide down to 960px wide. Anything less than that and it is OK for horizontal scroll bars to appear. The site must remain flush to the left and right edges of the screen.

At first I figured this was fairly easy to accomplish using media queries, some javascript and other modern "responsive" techniques. I have gone down that road and while it was my first experience with a full-blown responsive site, it wasn't too difficult. I had to do a lot of dynamic resizing of images, header sizes, text sizes, etc. Lots of work and testing but worth it. Or not??!!

Now I am realizing that mobile safari effectively has this technology built right in. Via viewport resizing. That is why on the ipad both a 960px and a 1200px wide site will snap to the edges of the browser window.

My question is 'is it possible to simulate viewport resizing in desktop browsers in the same way that mobile safari does it on iOS?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of, using percentages or ems, e.g.

```
body{
    width: 100%; 
}
content{
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
sidebar{
    width: 35%;
    float: right;
}
```

and then you could use media queries to resize text using ems